# Windows - Batch file to start Jar with "loop" parameters

Tags: batch-file

In linux I did with a simple .sh script:

```
p1=${1-hostname}
p2=${2-110}
for ((i=0;i<20;++i))
do
java -jar pathtomyjarfile $p1 $p2 $i&
sleep 10
```

How can I do this on Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file and enter this. This seems to be working on my machine.

```
@echo off
CLS
SET p1={1-hostname}
SET p2={2-110}

FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,20) DO (
    java -jar pathtomyjarfile %p1% %p2% %%i&timeout.exe /t 10
)

Pause
```

Comment: From a batch file? It will not work right if you copy and paste it into a command window; it hangs after 1 run.

Comment: Oh, and what version of Windows are you running this on?